# forecasting: problem with accuracy

Tags: r, forecasting

A few weeks back I used the following command:

**accuracy(train,test)**

where train and test are training and test data respectively. Last night I updated R and the forecast package and used the same command and I got error. After trying a little I used the following command

**accuracy(train,test[1:30])**

and it worked. (I was checking the accuracy of 30 forecasted values). 
Is there some change in the forecast package or did I do something wrong?

regards
Leo

Comment: I voted to close as no statistical content.  But to troubleshoot your problem I would start by checking that your forecast object "train" is forecasting as many time units ahead as you think it is; or (to put it another way), is there some reason to think that "test" is longer than the period your model is forecasting for?  I might hazard a guess that since you first wrote the command the data source you are using has grown and you might find that test is now 31 or more values?

Comment: +1 to @PeterEllis. This question would probably be best posted to the R help listserv.

Answer (score 1):

Found the following at the forecast's changelog.

> accuracy() can now figure out overlapping times for x and f.

This must be the reason. 
Thanks and regards
Leo